# Wordpress WPML replace Li a values

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

Greetings everyone,

Scenario: I am running a WPML (multilingual site) but the problem is that each language has its social media account and the backend only support one.

I would like to ask if it is possible to change the value of li a? Basically when I view Chinese content the default (English Social media accounts) will be changed into Chinese.

The Wordpress Theme 'Magnovus' dumps the social media using li a. What I want is to replace the value of anchor tag from English to Chinese.

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You can condition like

```js
if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE === 'en' ) {
    //for english language
} else if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE === '{chinese_lang_code}' ) {
    //for chinese language
}
```